# std::filesystem directory walk unstable with concurrent processes

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems, glob, std-filesystem

I am trying to write a cross-platform globbing method in C++. For this, I am trying to use the `std::filesystem` library to recurse through directories and compare paths against a provided path regex.

The code I attempt to use is:

```
std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string& regexPattern) {


    std::vector<std::string> matches

    fs::path currentPath = fs::current_path();
    fs::path dirPath = regexPattern;
    if (dirPath.is_relative()) {
        dirPath = currentPath / dirPath;
    }

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string path_upto_wildcard = "/";
    std::string str_dirPath = dirPath.string();

    while ((pos = str_dirPath.find("/")) != std::string::npos) {
        std::string token =str_dirPath.substr(0, pos);
        str_dirPath.erase(0, pos + 1);
        if (token == "" ) continue;

        cleanPattern += token + "/";
        path_upto_wildcard += token + "/";
    }


    dirPath = path_upto_wildcard;

    std::regex regEx(regexPattern);
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;
    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath); it != endIterator; ++it) {
        if ( std::regex_match(it->path().string(), regEx)) {
            matches.push_back(it->path().string());
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

which runs just fine when I compile and run the executable that uses this method. However, I use this code in an executable that I want to run 100 times concurrently (with different arguments) on the same machine, in the background. When I do this, I end up with some of the processes finishing just fine, but many others that throw the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: No such file or directory
(core dumped)
```

This happens if I use `std::filesystem` or `boost::filesystem`. However, if I write this glob method to use the  unix-dependant `glob.hpp` library, things run as expected, with no problems. The `glob.hpp` code is:

```
std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string& pattern) {
    glob_t g;
    glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE, nullptr, &g); // one should ensure glob returns 0!
    std::vector<std::string> filelist;
    filelist.reserve(g.gl_pathc);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g.gl_pathc; ++i) {
        filelist.emplace_back(g.gl_pathv[i]);
    }
    globfree(&g);
    return filelist;
}
```

I am unsure where the instability comes from, and if there is anything I can do about it?

Here is a Minimal working example:

```
#include <regex>
#include <filesystem>
#include <glob.h>
#include <iostream>


namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string& regexPattern) {

    std::vector<std::string> matches;


    fs::path currentPath = fs::current_path();
    fs::path dirPath = regexPattern;
    if (dirPath.is_relative()) {
        dirPath = currentPath / dirPath;
    }

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string path_upto_wildcard = "/";
    std::string str_dirPath = dirPath.string();
    while ((pos = str_dirPath.find("/")) != std::string::npos) {
        std::string token =str_dirPath.substr(0, pos);
        str_dirPath.erase(0, pos + 1);
        if (token == "" ) continue;
        if (token.find("*") !=  std::string::npos)  continue;

        path_upto_wildcard += token + "/";
    }


    dirPath = path_upto_wildcard;

    std::regex regEx(regexPattern);
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;

    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath); it != endIterator; ++it) {
        if ( std::regex_match(it->path().string(), regEx)) {
            matches.push_back(it->path().string());
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

int main() {
    std::vector dirs{"/mypath/a/.*XYZ*/.*",
                     "/mypath/b/.*XYZ*/.*",
                     "/mypath/c/.*XYZ*/.*",
                    };
    for (auto& dir : dirs) {
        std::vector<std::string> matches = glob(dir);
        for (auto& match : matches) {
            std::cout << match << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which can be compiled with

```
g++ test_globbing.cxx  -o test_globbing -std=c++17
```

and the effect can be tested by creating some text file `test_glob.txt` containing

```
./test_globbing
```

100 times (one per line), then running `run_in_bkg.sh` file that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash/

n=0
while read arg; do echo $n && ((n+=1)); eval ' $arg &> job_$(echo $n).log &'; sleep .2; done < $1
```

The effect is not always there and I can't get it to "always" happen, but every few runs you would see some jobs just failing, as the number of running processes increase.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] (especially the code that calls your glob function)?

Comment: Can you try [`it.increment`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/increment) instead of `++it`, and loop until the error code is clear?

Comment: @Nelfeal I am not sure what you mean by loop until the error code is clear?

Comment: @MohamedAymanAly Just a wild guess: possibly the OS runs out of file handles.

Comment: @Jabberwocky but how come this does not happen if i use the glob library instead? (I am not very well-versed in these libraries, so i apologise if my question is naive)

Comment: @MohamedAymanAly you're not naive, the question legitimate. Unfortunately I can't tell you, I was really just guessing. If it works with `glob`, it may just be by chance (still just a guess). Anyway the question is very clear now, and I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the directory structure should be to test your minimal working example.

Comment: @Nelfeal e.g. `~/dirA/testXYZ/test.txt, ~/dirB/testXYZ/test.txt,~/dirC/testXYZ/test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the standard does not specify how concurrent filesystem operations work, and in particular [it makes file system races undefined behavior](https://eel.is/c++draft/filesystems#fs.race.behavior).

Fortunately, there is another way to increment a directory iterator: [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator::increment`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/increment).
It takes a `std::error_code` argument and sets it instead of throwing a filesystem exception. So, instead of your for loop, I believe you can write something like this:

```
fs::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;
fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath);
while (it != endIterator) {
    if (std::regex_match(it->path().string(), regEx)) {
        matches.push_back(it->path().string());
    }

    std::error_code ec;
    do {
        it.increment(ec);
        // perhaps add a delay here
    } while (ec);
}
```

I cannot reproduce your issue even with your minimal working example (that I tried to translate to Windows as best I could), so I don't guarantee anything. I'm also unsure whether `it.increment` still increments `it` if it fails, so you might need to copy the iterator like this:

```
fs::recursive_directory_iterator endIterator;
fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath);
while (it != endIterator) {
    if (std::regex_match(it->path().string(), regEx)) {
        matches.push_back(it->path().string());
    }

    std::error_code ec;
    auto it_copy = it;
    do {
        it.increment(ec);
        if (ec) {
            it = it_copy;
        }
        // perhaps add a delay here
    } while (ec);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this! can you clarify a bit if this is to handle the excption or actually solve the problem? I am not sure I follow how passing the error code would "solve" the issue, but rather skip over it when it happens. Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't handle the exception/error at all, it just skips it. However, I assume it actually solves the problem: presumably, the error occurs because a file is accessed concurrently or maybe because the OS runs out of file handles, like @Jabberwocky guessed. That's not a fatal error, and in your case, you can just wait for it to go away and retry.